# Regular expression - get attribute value

Tags: regex, regex-group

Is anyone can help me to do this regex? I've been trying for hours without success.

in this code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="myScript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

"But not this"
```

I try to get with regex all the attribute value in green :

- fr,
- utf-8,
- viewport,
- width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,
- stylesheet,
- style.css,
- text/javascript,
- myScript.js

I have `"(.*?)"` that match all but also "But not This"...
How can I do this ?

Comment: Please try to come up with a more relevant, specific title to your question. Current title forces people to open the question to see what it is about.

Comment: You should specify the programming language, as getting an arbitrary amount of matches may or may not be available and the syntax varies too.

Comment: Regular expression syntax varies slightly between languages but for the most part the details are the same. I try the regex in https://regex101.com and then I use this in SWIFT 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct Regex.

- It works with all characters inside double quotes.
- Check if it's inside < >

Thanks @Reza Saadati for your help

```
(?<==)("[a-zA-Z0-9.\s\S\-']*?.*?)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it with

```
(?<=")[a-z]+
```

With Positive Lookbehind you will be searching for alphabats (a-z) **after** `"`.

See result: https://regex101.com/r/FaxkXM/1

### Update

This will match all attributes from your HTML tags.

```
(?<==")[a-zA-Z0-9.=\-,\/ ]+
```

See the result: https://regex101.com/r/i5hoP3/1

Comment: Is there a way to not write manually this character  " . =   - ! /" and just allow all between quote ?  Because if there another character,  it won't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I used the `R package` called `stringr` to do this.

```
a <- '<code a="fr" b="en" c="sp" d="it">'
    
    library(stringr)
    b <- str_extract_all(a, '(?<=\")[a-z]+(?=\")') %>% unlist()
> print(b)
[1] "fr" "en" "sp" "it"
```